# Array Based Implementation of a Vector

Tags: arrays, vector

Homework Assistance

*Describe an array based implementation of a vector such that inserting and 
removing at beginning and end of the vector can be done in constant time. Argue 
convincingly.*

Obviously this is impossible with a straight-up array. If you remove from the front, there will be a hole that needs to be filled in order to maintain the vector property. Of course, if we grab the next element over, we will need to do this n times, so the runtime will be linear, not constant.

Another way would be to grab the last element and stick it in the front, but what good is a data structure that scrambles your data?

What I have done so far is to create an array. The odd number indices are behind some point in the array (preferably the middle for size purposes, but it can be anywhere), then the even number indices are before that point. That takes up a whole bunch of memory and has lots of open slots if that special point is not the centre point. Worst case being 2n. However, it acts like there are no holes because it will always fill the next element out.

Insertion:

```
private int front = 0;
private int back = 0;
public void insertAtFront(int element)
{
    (front+1));
        dataArray[2*(front + 1) + 1] =  element;
        front++;
}

public void insertAtBack(int element)
{
    dataArray[2*(back+1)] = element;
    back++;
}
```

For removal, just decrement the front or the back. Then when accessing the array, only allow the values between front and back to be shown.

First, does this meet the requirements of a vector? Second, when removing, I am having some major issues figuring out how to get past that special centre point. Say you want to remove the entire array from the front, when you added everything from the back.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to use two arrays. The end of the first array is the "front". The end of the second array is the "back".

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with even and odd indices. But having a start index and an end index is basically the way to go - leave space empty at the front so that you can add elements there, and increment the start index again if you remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a circular array to allow you to add/remove both at the front and at the end efficiently.

There are other variations that could be applied: can you also find an implementation such that inserting/removing at the start, the end and (exactly) in the middle is efficient and has O(1) time?